# Weird layout for iOS app in Split View mode

Tags: bug, ios-app

Using Split View mode in iOS can result in a weird layout for the app:

> [image: post]

The post section looks very narrow. In particular some tags do not fit the width.

Another ultra narrow version:

> [image: toonarrow]

- App Version: 1.6.5.3
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.1 (Build 14E304)

Comment: What's "multiple apps mode"?

Comment: @user00001 mode for using 2 apps simultaneously. https://www.howtogeek.com/228955/how-to-use-multiple-apps-at-once-on-an-ipad/

Comment: I believe Apple officially refers to this feature as "[Split View](https://www.google.com/amp/www.cultofmac.com/326341/ios-9s-split-view-for-ipad-is-everything-you-hoped-it-would-be/amp/)"

Comment: @StevenVascellaro I just took the name from the [settings menu item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5u0DQ.jpg). Thanks for finding the official one.

Comment: @alexolut Wait, are you referring to the feature where you load a temporary version of the app on the side? If so, that might actually be "[Slide Over](http://www.cio.com/article/2957204/ios/ios-9-how-to-use-slide-over.html)". I'm not entirely sure

Comment: @StevenVascellaro as far as I understand: in Split View - 2 apps are active; in Slide Over - you can temporary open one app over another. Link from Apple: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207582

Comment: @alexolut Yes, that is correct. If both apps are active, then this is indeed Split View